# Tensorflow-probability transform event shape of JointDistribution

Tags: tensorflow-probability

I would like to create a distribution for n categorical variables C_1,.., C_n whose event shape is n. Using JointDistributionSequentialAutoBatched the event dimension is a list [[],..,[]]. For example for n=2

```py
import tensorflow_probability.python.distributions as tfd

probs = [
    [0.8, 0.2], # C_1 in {0,1}
    [0.3, 0.3, 0.4] # C_2 in {0,1,2}
    ]

D = tfd.JointDistributionSequentialAutoBatched([tfd.Categorical(probs=p) for p in probs])

>>> D
<tfp.distributions.JointDistributionSequentialAutoBatched 'JointDistributionSequentialAutoBatched' batch_shape=[] event_shape=[[], []] dtype=[int32, int32]>
```

How do I reshape it to get event shape [2]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few different approaches could work here:

1. Create a batch of Categorical distributions and then use `tfd.Independent` to reinterpret the batch dimension as the event:

```py
vector_dist = tfd.Independent(
  tfd.Categorical(
    probs=[
      [0.8, 0.2, 0.0],  # C_1 in {0,1}
      [0.3, 0.3, 0.4]  # C_2 in {0,1,2}
    ]),
  reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)
```

Here I added an extra zero to pad out `probs` so that both distributions can be represented by a single Categorical object.

2. Use the `Blockwise` distribution, which stuffs its component distributions into a single vector (as opposed to the JointDistribution classes, which return them as separate values):

```py
vector_dist = tfd.Blockwise([tfd.Categorical(probs=p) for p in probs])
```

3. The closest to a direct answer to your question is to apply the `Split` bijector, whose inverse is `Concat`, to the joint distribution:

```py
tfb = tfp.bijectors
D = tfd.JointDistributionSequentialAutoBatched(
  [tfd.Categorical(probs=[p] for p in probs])
vector_dist = tfb.Invert(tfb.Split(2))(D)
```

Note that I had to awkwardly write `probs=[p]` instead of just `probs=p`. This is because the `Concat` bijector, like `tf.concat`, can't change the tensor rank of its argument---it can concatenate small vectors into a big vector, but not scalars into a vector---so we have to ensure that its inputs are themselves vectors. This could be avoided if TFP had a `Stack` bijector analogous to `tf.stack` / `tf.unstack` (it doesn't currently, but there's no reason this couldn't exist).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out tfd.Blockwise, in my code I was actually using a JointDistributionCoroutine with trainable probs so I could not use solution 1. . I have ended up using  tfd.Blockwise as in its docstrings:`joint =tfd.JointDistributionCoroutine(model), d = tfd.Blockwise(joint)`
`